# Serving a GeoTIFF as ImageWMS in OpenLayers resizing issue

Tags: openlayers, geotiff-tiff, mapserver

I'm sure I missed a step which is leading to this issue of reprojecting/resizing my imageWMS layer. I started with netCDF that wasn't georeferenced so I gdal_translated it to a GeoTIFF and then applied:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Float32 -sds -a_srs "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84"
```

[image: zoomed_out]

And zoomed in:
[image: zoomed_in]

My OpenLayers layer:

```
new ol.layer.Image({
                      opacity: .5,
                      source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
                        url: "/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=\\ms4w\\apps\\tinyows\\myDemo\\WMS.map&layer=CHLLLL&mode=map",
                        params: {'LAYERS': 'CHLLLL'},
                        serverType: 'mapserver',
                        ratio: 1,
                        projection: 'EPSG:4326'
                      })
                    });
```

Mapfile:

```
LAYER  
  NAME "CHLLLL"
  DATA ".\output_1.tif"
  #EXTENT "0 0 8640 4320" //causes no show
  TYPE RASTER
  PROJECTION
    "init=epsg:4326"
  END
  STATUS ON
END
```

And my gdalinfo on my TIFF file:

```
gdalinfo output_1.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: output_1.tif
Size is 8640, 4320
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["unknown",
        SPHEROID["WGS84",6378137,298.257223563]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]]
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0, 4320.0)
Upper Right ( 8640.0,    0.0)
Lower Right ( 8640.0, 4320.0)
Center      ( 4320.0, 2160.0)
Band 1 Block=8640x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
```

I've tried various extents to no luck so I think it's over my head at this point.

Comment: putting aside any projection issues, you'll need to lose the `mode=map&` as this won't give you a WMS response.  Also `layer=CHLLLL&` shouldn't be part of the service URL, it should be just: `http://your-service/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=\\ms4w\\apps\\tinyows\\myDemo\\WMS.map&`

Comment: Awesome thanks! Applied those and it made the projection worse, albeit I bet I'm closer than before.

Comment: EXTENT looks wrong it should be in the units of the projection, so if your data is in epsg:4326 then EXTENT should be in degrees, take a look at: http://onegeology.org/service_provision/server_setup/mapserver.html#configuring-mapserver

Comment: EXTENT seem to be commented out in the map file so it does not have an effect. But gdalinfo shows that the image is not georeferenced right. Projection is set but corner coordinates are wrong.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking. The corners from gdal_info should read -180 -90 180, 90 because it's a whole world layer. I changed the extent to represent degrees and it didn't have the expected effect because I think of the improper georeferencing.